# htaccess proxy redirect for root and only root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect only the root domain (and not its subfolders) to another URL, without changing the address. I'm using .htaccess and redirecting with [P] flag, which works fine for subdirectories but not for the root.

When writing the following .htaccess everything works fine, but in 'regular' redirect and not proxy:

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewriterule ^$ http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/ [R,L]
```

When changing to mod_proxy, it doesn't work (does not redirect without an error):

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewriterule ^$ http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/ [P]
```

It is important to me to keep the original address in the browser address bar.
any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably doesn't work because the rule doesn;t apply.
In most cases the root is not empty, but contains a request to index.html or default.html . Give this snippet a try:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "default.html"  "http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/"  [P]
```